# Why Nginx return 403 Forbidden error even using root user

Tags: nginx, centos7

I have installed Nginx in CentOS 7 64bit with the command `yum install nginx` everything goes well till I do not change the default configuration.

But when I want to change the root directory to some other location in `conf.d/default.conf` e.g: `/home/ftpuser`

```
location / {
    root   /home/ftpuser;
    index  index.html;
 }
```

And the user in `nginx.conf` to `ftpuser`

```
user  ftpuser;
```

Which `ftpuser` is a normal user and has the home directory in the `/home` location, but Nginx returns the 403 error. Even I created a new `test` directory in the `/home` location with permissions `777`, Nginx still returns 403.

And then I changed the user from `ftpuser` to root `user`, the problem still exists.

And then I changed the permission of the `/home/fptuser` folder to `777` by: `chmod 777 ftpuser`, but problem still exists.

I have searched a lot and gave the top privileges to Nginx why it still returns 403?

If anyone knows please let me know the reason and the way to solve it!

**Nginx version:** 1.17.6

**UPDATE:**
Error log:

> 2019/11/30 20:39:19 [error] 2195#2195: *10 open()
>   "/home/ftpuser/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client:
>   192.168.133.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.133.134"

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated the question, error log says permission problem.

Comment: @emix I know that, but I don't want to disable SElinux. It is not a good way to solve because of security problems.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but strictly server related. This is a SElinux issue. You can find more details in the logs.

Comment: @emix Yes, it is why I used Nginx and centos7 tags, not java or c++, ... etc. How to solve this then, disabling SElinux is not a solution.

Comment: @emix the error log says the above message which is in the question.

Comment: I’m not talking about NGINX logs but system logs.

Answer (score -1):

After searching, finally, I found the solution.

It is the **SELinux Policies** problem.

So how to fix it?

Just go to [this](https://github.com/northbright/Notes/blob/master/nginx/configure-selinux-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-of-nginx-on-centos.md) link and do the steps, it will solve the SELinux Policies problem.

I hope it helps others if they have the same problem with Nginx in CentOS 7!!